# Mozart/Oz Gives Error : expression at statement position

Tags: class, methods, attributes, oz, mozart

Consider the following code:

```
declare
class Test
   attr L
   meth init L:=nil end
   meth put(X) {Browse @L} end
   meth get {Browse @L} end
   meth isEmpty @L==nil end
   meth getList @L end
   meth setNil L:=nil end
   meth union(C) {Browse @L} end
end
```

When I compile this class it **gives error : expression at statement position**. I'm checking my little code for about an hour to fix this error but got no luck. Please help me find the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

your methods cannot return something! `isEmpty`and `getList` should be

```
meth isEmpty(R) R=(@L==nil) end
meth getList(R) R=@L end
```

and you can use

```
T={New Test init}
{Browse {T isEmpty($)}}
```

to do 'as if it had a return value'

Actually `{Browse {T isEmpty($)}}` is the same as
`local R in {T isEmpty(R)} {Browse R} end`

sorry for my bad english